# Post API parameter empty - not reading from request body even after using [FromBody] attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a simple `Post` API that requires reading from request body. But after requesting via Postman and debugging, I am getting the complex parameter for both `POST` and `PUT` API methods empty (`id` for PUT is received successfully).

My code goes like this:

```
public class Model
{
    int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
    string NationalIDNumber { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeRegController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Model createEmpModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _employee.EmployeeCreate(createEmpModel);

        return Ok(new { Message = "Employee created" });
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] Model updateEmp)
    {
        _employee.EmployeeUpdate(id, updateEmp);
        return Ok(new { Message = "Employee updated" });
    }
}
```

JSON string:

```
{
    "BusinessEntityID": 6,
    "NationalIDNumber": "658797903"
}
```

I took several suggestions from internet but without any luck so far:

- Removed `[ApiController]`
- Tried working with and without `[FromBody]`
- Changed `Content-Type` in request header
- Ensured same field names for model and JSON string

Comment: Try marking your model properties as Public.

Comment: Model is a reserved keyword in ASP.Net Core/MVC.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper Tried with a different name but that didn't work

Comment: @quaabaam Making model properties Public did help. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Didn't notice this myself but Just making the model properties Public worked out in my case.
Thanks again to @quaabaam for that worthy comment.